Keycloak doesn't return token
I'm facing a strang issue with keycloak.
My application is in .Net 8. I managed, 2 years ago, to make it work with keycloak on docker in my dev environment and now I'm trying to make it works with keycloak on cloud iam.
I create realm, client, configure openid, add openid in my aplication (since 2 years we removed keycloak).
I when I hit an authorize attribute into a controller, keycloak login page is called, I logged into keycloak and came back to my callback login page, but .net throw an error in AuthenticationHandlerProvider->GetHandlerAsync :

IDX10000: The parameter 'token' cannot be a 'null' or an empty object.  (Parameter 'token')

I'm not capable to understand why I have this error.
Someone could help please?
Here configuration into program.cs :
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    //Sets cookie authentication scheme
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(cookie =>
{
    //Sets the cookie name and maxage, so the cookie is invalidated.
    cookie.Cookie.Name = "keycloak.cookie";
    cookie.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    cookie.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    cookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
    cookie.LoginPath = "/Authenticate/Index";
    cookie.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authenticate/AccessDenied";
    cookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1800);
}).AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    //options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.ClaimsIssuer = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Keycloak:ServerRealm");
    //Keycloak server
    options.Authority = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Keycloak:ServerRealm");
    //Keycloak client ID
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Keycloak:ClientIdPortal");
    //Keycloak client secret
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Keycloak:ClientSecret");
    //Keycloak .wellknown config origin to fetch config
    options.MetadataAddress = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Keycloak:Metadata");
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    //Require keycloak to use SSL
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true
    };
    //Save the token
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    //Token response type, will sometimes need to be changed to IdToken, depending on config.
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    //SameSite is needed for Chrome/Firefox, as they will give http error 500 back, if not set to unspecified.
    options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
    options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role,
        ValidateIssuer = true
    };
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Authenticate/Index");
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Keycloak:Issuer");
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        },
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message received");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Authentication failed: {context.Exception.Message}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

And keycloak config in appsettings :
{
"Keycloak": {
    "AuthenticationURL": "https://my-server-url/auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "ClientId": "my-client",
    "ClientName": "my-client",
    "ClientSecret": "my-client-secret",
    "Issuer": "https://my-server-url/auth/realms/majorel/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    "KeycloakURL": "https://my-server-url/auth",
    "LogoutURL": "https://my-server-url/auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
    "Metadata": "https://my-server-url/auth/realms/majorel/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    "Realm": "majorel",
    "ServerRealm": "https://my-server-url/auth/realms/majorel",
    "TokenURL": "https://my-server-url/auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token"
}

}

could you post some code about how do you configure keycloak auth in program.cs and appsettings?

done, see below

What is the use of OnRedirectToIdentityProvider... Could you delete that and try?

And I didn't see "Keycloak:ClientIdPortal" in appsettings.

It is renamed in ClientId

If I remove OnRedirectToIdentityProvider I get this error :
Cannot redirect to the authorization endpoint, the configuration may be missing or invalid.,

I can test these codes with no error. I suggest you create new keycloak client and try.
